# How to managed two sql queries in ASP.Net (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

So what I'm trying to do is once I click a button. I want one sql query to insert values to the "Return_Process" Table and another sql query to delete data from the matching loan ID in another table, which is "Loan_Process".

This is the code I have written but its not deleting anything, its inserting the values to the return process but not deleting it from the loan process.

```
    //Global variable declaration
    string path;
    string sql;
    string sql2;
    //create a method for database connection
    public void connection()
    {
        //connection string
        path = @"Data Source=NATHAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ASP;Integrated Security=True";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            connection();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(path);
            con.Open();

            //try
            {
                sql = "INSERT INTO Return_Process (Return_ID, FIne, Actual_Returned_Date, Loan_ID) VALUES ('" + txtRID.Text + "','" + txtfine.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + txtLID.Text + "')";
                sql2 = "Delete FROM Loan_Process WHERE Loan_ID='"+txtLID+"'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //lblerrormsg.Visible = true;
                //lblerrormsg.Text = "Success";
                con.Close();
                //GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            //catch (SqlException)
            //{
            //    //lblerrormsg.Visible = true;
            //    //lblerrormsg.Text = "Invalid";
            //}


            con.Close();
            //GridView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
}
```

}

I'm pretty bad at ASP.net, so if someone could tell me what to do to execute both queries at the same time, would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Combine both queries in one (separated by `;`).  Also use `@parameters` in the query.

Comment: I'm sorry like I said im awful at asp.net just was handed a project for my course and no clue how to do this.

So like sql = "query1" ; "query 2"? like that or?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
//your code
sql = "INSERT INTO Return_Process (Return_ID, FIne, Actual_Returned_Date, Loan_ID)"
    + " VALUES (@rid, @fine, @retDate, @lid); " //note ; inside
    + "Delete FROM Loan_Process WHERE Loan_ID=@lid;";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@rid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int.Parse(txtRID.Text);
//similar for 3 remaining parameters. Just set correct SqlDbType
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. What do you set the correct sqldbtype? For my code what would it be? sorry trying to keep up but im really weak in this area. I put in your code and it says Int.Parse and SqpDbtype.int does not exist in this current context

Comment: `Int` for integer type, `DateTime` for dates, and so on. Check your DB schema (table definition).